# How to build an architecture for an already existing React Native application

Tags: react-native, architecture

So I have made a simple React Native recipe app for my Bachelor Thesis to use as a base for implementing analytic tools. I have been getting questions about what the architecture is of my demo application and how those analytic tools will fit in.

The thing is that I have no clue on how to make an architecture for a simple React Native application.

I do have to mention that this react native application is build in Managed Expo.

So the Recipe application itself has a stackNavigator with a tab navigator containing 3 tabs.
1 tab for the list of recipes, 1 tab to check personal recipes, 1 tab to check recipes based on leftovers. Only the first tab really works there you can like a recipe view its details and simulate buying a recipe (which ofcource is just a regular button).

So there are 4 different screens 1 for each tab and the recipe detail. There are also 3 custom components, 1 representing the cell of a recipe in the list, 1 for the custom tabbar and 1 for custom tabItem. The only thing left is a static list of recipes in .json file.

That's literally all there is to.

So is there anyone who can help me with this?

Thanks in advance

## Edit 1:

So far I found the [C4 model](https://c4model.com/) which is specific for software architecture. I also find it very descriptive and easy to understand. The main issue I have is that I have no clue what I have to put in the component diagram.

Comment: I think your question is about designing the navigation structure for a react native app. There are lots of examples in the set-up guides https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation. However, if you have something implemented already and it's not working, show your code.

Comment: It's not about designing or building an application. It's about building an architecture (image) from an already existing and working application.

Comment: If you're asking about generating a diagram of the navigation structure of your app, I have never heard of a tool that does that. If you're asking about making an executable build we need a lot more information about what platforms/stores you want to publish to, and what problems you've ran in to. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: They just asked me to create an image that shows the architecture of my mobile application. So like I said previously I just need an image of the architecture of my mobile app. But I have no clue on how to make it.

Comment: My concern is that when someone asks about the architecture of an app, they're usually referring to the system architecture, not the navigational structure. But it sounds like your navigation is quite simple. I would draw it on paper...or a whiteboard, or use google draw or figma. It would take so much longer to figure out how to generate it. Look up UML, there's a bunch of diagraming standards.

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I didn't know what to show them exactly, also I didn't want to use UML because I thought it might be a bit too technical for people who don't know UML. Which is something that has to be avoided in a bachelor thesis, as it has to be clear when people read through them.

Comment: Look at how Material communicates navigation, with diagrams, animations and videos https://material.io/design/navigation/navigation-transitions.html#about-navigation-transitions. Consider making a video of you navigating through the screens of your app. Consider using something like Adobe XD to make an interactive experience. Maybe draw it up in Sketch or Figma, indicating where the navigational triggers are, and where they transition.